Use aggregate result again on another
I am trying to use a GROUP BY query with DuckDB. I am having trouble with some nested aggregates and am unsure of how to approach it (in SQL land). For each aggregate group, I want to:

Compute the mean of aggregate
Then, in each aggregate, for a given price, subtract that aggregate to compute another aggregate.

I have tried looking at Arrow Vectorized UDF functions but I can't seem to find details on if they're supported with DuckDB?
The current code I'm working with, from a parquet file that has a price & size at a given timestamp:
    df = duckdb.sql(f"""
                        SELECT timestamp,
                          first(price) AS start
                          sum(size) AS vol,
                          sum(price * size).divide(vol) AS mean,
                          sum(price - mean) AS subtract_mean, ## This line does not ###work
                        FROM '{file_raw_parquet}'
                        GROUP BY timestamp
                    """)

I marked the line I'm having issues with. Should I alternatively compute the mean in a different table so it's ,, then JOIN it to the main table, then compute the GROUP BY?
I found a similar thread talking about re-using the group by statement: Re-use aggregate result but was slightly different than what I was after.
Thanks!

Sample data and expected results would help immensely. I have no idea what "compute the mean of aggregate" means, or what "for a given price, subtract that aggregate to compute another aggregate" in this context.

a simple worked example of 'Compute the mean of aggregate' would help avoid the ambiguity around this.

You can't use aggregation result within the same aggregation.
In general case you could use window functions to precalculate aggregations.
But in your case you can work around it - mean is the same for every row within timestamp, so you can change your formula sum(price - mean) to sum(price) - count(*) * mean:
duckdb.sql("""
    select
        timestamp,
        sum(size) as vol,
        sum(price * size).divide(vol) as mean,
        sum(price) - count(*) * mean as subtract_mean
    from '{file_raw_parquet}'
    group by
        timestamp
""")

